# Spawning processes on a job stack

Tags: process, scheduling

I have a hobbyist server on which I want users to upload a file, and then receive the overcome of some processing (server-side) over the given file.
I am doing the processing synchronously so that for each user request, the server spawns a new process. However, I wanted to do it asynchronously, so that the server would not spawn 1 million processes if it was accessed by 1 million users. (never going to happen, I just want to learn about server scalability)
By this, I mean the following:
After the server receives the to-be-processed file, it adds a job (something like "process file_uuid.xyz > output_uuid.zyx") to some sort of process queue. So that this process will only be run when all the previous ones are finished.

I am almost sure linux has some way of doing this, I just cant figure out how to search for it.

Comment: This [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/220364/how-to-run-commands-as-in-a-queue) article may help you.

Comment: FYI: By *synchronously* you mean *in parallel* and by *asynchronously* you mean *serially*.  "Synchronicity" is a distinctly different topic ;)

Comment: Check out RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, or other queueing systems. Look at Celery if you are using `python`.